# Parse.com array query order

Tags: android, parse-platform

Lets say that there is an array with 10 objects in it. Each object has a different array value. If I want to query all 10 objects from order from highest array value to lowest, what parse method do I use?

I have looked through the official documentation for a while and still can't find the answer.

Thanks :)

Comment: Can't be done with the parse query.  The ordering methods work only on the simple scalar properties like numbers and strings, not arrays or pointers.  The solution is to design the query only to capture the objects you want (not order them), then sort them after the query.  This is a good candidate for a cloud function.

Comment: Would it be possible to compute and store the value as a separate field on the objects?

Comment: @Vlad.  Yes, I should have mentioned, you can sort queries on a scalar property, and you could derive that scalar property from the object and save it with the object on a beforeSave.

Comment: @danh So if I have a class TestPost, and it has two columns 'value' and 'text'. I cannot order these without using cloud code?

Comment: What types are those columns?

Comment: @danh sorry I should have been more clear. 'value' is a number and 'text' is a string.

Comment: Oh, its very simple to sort based on strings or numbers.  In android, you say `query.orderByAscending("value")` or `query.orderByDescending("text")`, etc.

Comment: @danh If I were to use a limit, lets say .limit = 5. If I then did query.orderByDecending("value") ,would it only order and display the first 5 rows it found or would it display 5 rows out of all the rows that have the highest value.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @danh I now know how to do this. To perform a query based on the order of a value contained in each row, you use the method query.orderByAscending() or query.orderByDescending().

For detailed descriptions of these methods, you can find them here: https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseQuery.html

Comment: looks like you have it.  the limit is applied last, so sorting and limiting would give you the top N or the bottom N of all objects.  (limit must be < 1000)